# Use es7 decorator in jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, jestjs

I use decorators in my project, but it seems the babel-jest do not support this new experiment feature
I find some support from this [github issue](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/3108) ===> which replace babel-jest with webpack-babel-jest, and it fix the decorator problem. But a new problem comes in when i run npm run test ==> "ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined"
It seems we need regenerator-runtime.(I use redux-saga in my project) I can't get a way to fix this.

```
package.json {
"babel-core": "^6.7.6",
"babel-eslint": "^7.2.3",
"babel-jest": "^21.2.0",
"babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
"babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^2.7.1",
"babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
"babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
"babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx-source": "^6.22.0",
"babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
"babel-polyfill": "^6.23.0",
"babel-preset-es2015": "^6.6.0",
"babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
"babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.5.0",
"css-loader": "^0.23.1",
"enzyme": "^3.1.0",
"enzyme-adapter-react-15.4": "^1.0.3",
"jest": "^21.2.1",
"node-sass": "^3.4.2",
"react-addons-test-utils": "^15.4.2",
"regenerator-runtime": "^0.11.0" }
```

---

```
   .babelrc {
{
"presets": [
    "es2015",
    "react",
    "stage-0"
],
"plugins": [
    "transform-decorators-legacy",
    "transform-react-jsx-source",
    "transform-class-properties",
["transform-runtime", {
  "polyfill": false,
  "regenerator": true
    }
],
"env": {
    "development": {

        "presets": [
            "react-hmre"
        ]
    },
    "test": {
        "presets": [
            "es2015",
            "react",
            "stage-0"
        ]
    }
}
}
}
```

Comment: Its better to explicitly `import * from "regenerator-runtime";` in every file with failing tests

Answer (score 0):

> I can't get a way to fix this.

This is well-known issue of regenerator-transform babel plugin, which is commonly used for transpiling code with sagas.

See verbose explanation here: [Unable to export generator functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47227385/unable-to-export-generator-functions/47280513#47280513)