# Unable to export generator functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, generator, redux-saga

When attempting to export a generator function in order to use in a Redux-Saga, ES-Lint is telling me that I have an error in my code:

```
[eslint] Expected a function declaration. (func-style)
```

It exports just fine the way that it is currently, and the rule is currently being ignored:

```
/*eslint-disable func-style*/
const myExampleSaga = function* () {
        yield takeEvery('DO_SOMETHING_REQUEST', andDoThisFunc);
};
export default myExampleSaga;
```

I am more or less okay with the fact that ES-Lint does not support generators (or at least it would seem that way), however **I would like to know why the following code does not work**:

```
export default function* () {
    yield takeEvery('DO_SOMETHING_REQUEST', andDoThisFunc);
}
```

With the following error message:

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'regeneratorRuntime.mark')
```

The error message is being thrown from my rootSaga, which looks like this:

```
/*eslint-disable func-style*/
export const rootSaga = function* rootSaga() {
    yield all([
        spawn(myExampleSaga)
    ]);
};
```

Can anyone tell me why the above code is invalid? I think it has something to do with hoisting, however I was not able to find any reason why that would be invalid.

Comment: try this: `/*eslint func-style: ["error", "expression"]*/` read abot the rule here: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/func-style#rule-details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can anyone tell me why the above code is invalid?

This is well-known issue of `regenerator-transform` [babel plugin](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-regenerator/), which is commonly used for transpiling code with sagas. That issue also affects `async` functions, because they are implemented by `regenerator-transform` mechanism too.

```
export default function* () {
    yield takeEvery('DO_SOMETHING_REQUEST', andDoThisFunc);
}
```

After [transforming that code](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&code_lz=AQ4UwDwBwewJwC7ACZgGYEMCuAbJasA7AYwQEsZCAqYACgEpgBvAKFHeAE8ywdlgEGANZgAogDcwcTrQDkAEQDyAfQDKigLKiAKgAkAkgDkA4soBKogIoBVUau2yANMAyFk8mNoAWZAM4AxImJ6AG42UABfcJAgA&debug=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&targets=&version=6.26.0) , there can be two issues. First is omitting inclusion of `regenerator-runtime` dependency, which is mandatory. Second is function hoisting, so if occurrence order matters, it should be specified implicitly.

Correct solution is:

```
import 'regenerator-runtime';
const mySaga = function* () {
    yield takeEvery('DO_SOMETHING_REQUEST', andDoThisFunc);
}
export default mySaga;
```